# The Texture looks paler in the preview compared with the UV map

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

My issue is shown as below:

[image]

The texture of the face in Blender is paler if compared with the substance painter preview and the texture shown on the right side of the image.

As you can see, I am on material mode, I tried to both change the studiolights and their value but it only affects the hair which is actually unfinished.

I don't understand if I am missing some settings, the nodes are simple and straightforward, it's just an image connected with the output.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be your Color Management settings.

Blender defaults it to "Filmic", which alters colors. Try setting it to "Standard" :

[image]

Comment: Alright that did the trick, thanks a lot!